# Where can one find motherboard block diagrams when the manufacture doesn't provide them?

Tags: motherboard

Hoping there is a site off the beaten path I didnt pick up through my searches.
Thank you

Comment: If the manufacturer doesn't publish the schematics, then I'm fairly certain you'll never find them, unless they're leaked and/or someone takes the time to reverse engineer them. Either way, there's not a specific place online where people post leaked/reverse-engineered motherboard electrical schematics.

Comment: @SamForbis I think it is an answer.

Comment: If your question would be closed, you might find further help on https://electronics.stackexchange.com or on https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com . Note, there are many, not intuitive requirements, how can you ask a question, I suggest to follow them.

Answer (score 0):

Posted as an answer instead of a comment:

If the manufacturer doesn't publish the schematics, then I'm fairly certain you'll never find them, unless they're leaked and/or someone takes the time to reverse engineer them. Either way, there's not a specific place online where people post leaked/reverse-engineered motherboard electrical schematics.